# Xamarin studio : class not visible, yet in solution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, solution

Has anyone had this issue:

I have a class for which code autocompletion works (it can see its members, properties, etc.), I can hit F12 and see the class code. But, the class cannot be seen in the solution explorer, nor can I add it because Xamarin Studio claims it has already been added to the solution.

Switching tabs in the notebook usually highlights the classes in the solution explorer, but for this single class, it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class already exists in the file system. In VisualStudio you can choose to show hidden files in solution explorer and include it back in to the project. In Xamarin Studio you could right click on solution and choose `Open Containing Folder`, find the file on the disk and delete it, so you can add it again.

Comment: It turned out to be a good idea. I closed my solution, moved the file outside the project folder, added it from this location, let Xamarin Studio complain the file is outside the project and let me choose to move it, then the file is added and is displayed inside the solution. Thanks !